# Releasing an ivar with the Copy property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

If I have a class

```
@interface Foo {
    NSString *temp;
}

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *temp;

@end
```

I understand that upon assignment, the old temp will get released and the new one will be assigned using `temp = [newTemp copy]`. And going by memory management rules, you are supposed to do `[temp release]` in the dealloc method of Foo, right?

What I don't understand is what happens if the setter was never used - you still have the `[temp release]` in the dealloc, so it's releasing something with a retain count of 0. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

1. Since you never set it, it's `nil`.  Sending `release` to `nil` is just fine.  So no problem there.
2. Your `init` routine makes a default value for `temp`.  Then it is a real object, and sending it `release` is also ok.

No problem all around!  In neither case are you sending a message to an object with a retain count of 0.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for replying so quickly!